# how to join two table with relation in yii?

Tags: php, yii, crud, cgridview

I have two tables company and users. In user table there is a field named company_id which relates users to the company. But not all users will be related to the company. There will be users without company id. Now I need to list the users in grid view using the relation. I related company to the users using the relation in yii.

```
public function relations() {
    return array('company' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Company', 'company_id'));
}
```

But it showed error when I tried to display company name of each users. I think the issue is with the users which are not related to company. I searched for the answers, came up with the left join operation while giving relation.

```
public function relations() {
    return array('company' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Company', 'company_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT JOIN',
            'on' => "(company.id=company_id)"));
}
```

But this too gives me error.

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'company_id' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `company`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `company`.`name` AS `t1_c1`, `company`.`telephone` AS `t1_c2`, `company`.`description` AS `t1_c3`, `company`.`address` AS `t1_c4`, `company`.`status` AS `t1_c5` FROM `company` `company` WHERE ((company.id=company_id)) AND (`company`.`id`=:ypl0)

Please help me in this issue. I am a beginner in yii.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `'on' => "(company.id=company_id)"`

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below links to understand how Yii relations work:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/181/relations-belongs_to-versus-has_one/

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr